# Can we use jquery wildcard selector with ajax helper UpdateTargetId

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Just curious to know can we specify jquery wild card selector for **UpdateTargetId**  ?

as we know that when we work with `@Ajax.ActionLink or @Ajax.BeginForm` then we need to specify html element id where new html data is inserted into it.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("View  All Student Info", "AllStudent", "Home", new AjaxOptions  
   {  
       UpdateTargetId = "divAllStudent",  
       OnBegin = "fnOnBegin",  
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,  
       HttpMethod = "GET",  
       LoadingElementId = "imgloader",  
       OnSuccess= "fnSuccess",  
       Confirm="Do you want to get all student info ?????"  
   }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

so tell me can we use jquery wild card selector with **UpdateTargetId** like this way `UpdateTargetId ="$('[id$=divAllStudent]')"` ?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: i did not try because i am not sure does it work or not. so curious to know does it work?

Comment: jQuery documentation says syntax is `jQuery( "[attribute$='value']" )`. Note quotation marks around value. Perhaps you need `$('[id$="divAllStudent"]')`. See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation for AjaxOptions.UpdateTargetId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.updatetargetid(v=vs.118).aspx)

> Gets or sets the ID of the DOM
>   element to update by using the response from the server.

No mention of jQuery. So I think it only works with an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround I found - `AjaxOptions.UpdateTargetId` generates `data-ajax-update="mentioned_id"` attribute. Skipping the AjaxOptions property and adding the attribute manually using htmlAttributes did the trick.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Link text", "Edit", new { id = attachment.AttachmentId},
            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET"},
            new { data_ajax_update = "YOUR_SELECTOR_HERE"})
```